# React Native, how to get values from multiple TextInputs into one object by pressing a Button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to put values from different `TextInput`'s into 1 object. I'm new to React in general and don't have a firm grasp of states yet. So far my code is like this:

```
function App() {

  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState()
  const [firstText, setFirstText] = useState()
  const [secondText, setSecondText] = useState()

  function textChange(enteredText) {
    console.log(enteredText) //I want firstText and secondText here
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <Text style={styles.header}>Great one!</Text>

      <TextInput 
        value={firstText}
        onChangeText={text=>setEnteredText(text)}
        style={styles.input} 
        placeholder='1st text' />

      <TextInput 
        value={secondText}
        onChangeText={text=>setEnteredText(text)}
        style={styles.input} 
        placeholder='2nd text' />

      <Button
        onPress={()=>textChange(enteredText)}
        title='Submit'
        color='orange' />

    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close! What you want (enteredText) shouldn't actually be a state. It logically **flows** from the first and second texts, so you can just have it be a constant.

Like this:

```js
function App() {

  // changed the default state to be an empty string instead of
  // the default undefined value. But either would work.
  const [firstText, setFirstText] = useState("")
  const [secondText, setSecondText] = useState("")

  const enteredText = firstText + secondText

  // I'd probably rename this function to "handleSubmit"
  function textChange() {
    console.log(enteredText)
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <Text style={styles.header}>Great one!</Text>

      <TextInput 
        value={firstText}
        onChangeText={text=>setFirstText(text)}
        style={styles.input} 
        placeholder='1st text' />

      <TextInput 
        value={secondText}
        onChangeText={text=>setSecondText(text)}
        style={styles.input} 
        placeholder='2nd text' />

      <Button
        onPress={textChange}
        title='Submit'
        color='orange' />

    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Note how I changed the `onChangeText` callbacks for the `TextInput`s**

So you set `firstText` and `secondText` in their respective `onClick`s. Whenever the state is updated, the component rerenders, and runs all the code in the function body. the constant `enteredText` will be created on each run, and will always be the most recent concatenation of the two states.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow it's so simple. I was going down the path to unnecessary complexity haha. One question, can I simply form `enteredText` to a json object so I can use it around?

Comment: Sure! Just do `const enteredText = {first: firstText, second: secondText}` (or whatever key names you want for your object)

Answer (score 2):

You coud listen to `firstText` and `secondText` with `useEffect` and put them inside `enteredText` every time they change, like so:

```js
function App() {
  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState();
  const [firstText, setFirstText] = useState();
  const [secondText, setSecondText] = useState();

  function textChange(enteredText) {
    console.log(enteredText); // will gives you {firstText : "whatever", secondText: "firstText"}
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setEnteredText({
      firstText,
      secondText,
    });
  }, [firstText, secondText]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>Great one!</Text>

      <TextInput
        value={firstText}
        onChangeText={(text) => setFirstText(text)}
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="1st text"
      />

      <TextInput
        value={secondText}
        onChangeText={(text) => setSecondText(text)}
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="2nd text"
      />

      <Button
        onPress={() => textChange(enteredText)}
        title="Submit"
        color="orange"
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for setting state that depends on other state, but I think it's likely the requester doesn't actually need an additional state here (see my answer).

Comment: If he won't use `enteredText` as a state somewhere, yeah you are right. And thanks for the edit of my answer :)

Comment: No problem! It was easy to miss.

Comment: Once I get my head wrapped around useState, I will be practicing using useEffect. I'm an older dude coming from LAMP/jQuery learning React and Mongo